# Stability results by estimation of energy

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

If we consider, for $a,c\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\begin{cases}u_t=u_{xx}+cu_x+au& \text{ on }x\in (-L,L)\\u(-L)=u(L), u_x(-L)=u_x(L) & \text{ periodic boundary conditions}\end{cases}
$$we have 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\lVert u\rVert_2^2=-2\lVert u_x\rVert_2^2+2a\lVert u\rVert_2^2\leq 2a\lVert u\rVert_2^2
$$
and hence the energy estimation
$$
\lVert u\rVert_2^2\leq e^{2at}\lVert u_0\rVert_2^2
$$

Can we deduce some stability results (for the zero solution I guess) from this?

Am I right that we have stability iff $\lVert u\rVert_2^2$ is bounded?

If yes, then we should have stability iff $a<0$?

---

By the way: The spectrum is given by
$$
\lambda=-\frac{\pi^2\ell^2}{L^2}+i\frac{\pi\ell}{L}c+a,~\ell\in\mathbb{Z},
$$

and the rightmost point on the real line is therefore $(a,0)$. Hence for $a<0$ we should have spectral stability. Therefore it would be somehow nice if for the energy method approach we would have stability for $a<0$ as well.